# Why bother casting the return value since the type has been specified when calling the function?

Tags: unity-game-engine, casting

I am learning Editor Script of Unity recently, and I come across a piece of code in Unity Manual like this:

```
EditorWindowTest window  = (EditorWindowTest)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(EditorWindowTest), true, "My Empty Window");
```

I don't know why bother casting the result with (EditorWindowTest) again since the type has been specified in the parameter field of GetWindow().

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple overloads of the [EditorWindow.GetWindow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.GetWindow.html) method.

The one used in your code snippet is one of the non-generic ones. It accepts a Type argument which it can use at runtime to create the right type of window. However, since it doesn't use generics, it's not possible to know the type of the window at compile time, so the method just returns an EditorWindow, as that's the best it can do.

You can hover over a method in your IDE to see the return type of any method for yourself.

[image]

When using one of the generic overloads of the GetWindow method, you don't need to do any manual casting, since the method already knows at compile time the exact type of the window and returns an instance of that type directly.

[image]

The generic variants should be used when possible, because it makes the code safer by removing the need for casting at runtime, which could cause exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you closely look, GetWindow's return type is EditorWindow. Not the EditorWindowTest, so typecasting makes sense.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.GetWindow.html